# Kubernetes: update configMap with custom resources

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

We have an application that needs to read initialization parameters from a file.  Now a configMap is used to store these as data and mounted as a volume.

However update the configMap will not trigger a rollout update of pods.  So I am thinking create a custom resource that stores the parameters and create a configMap when it is created or updated and a custom controller to trigger a rollout of pods or somehow mount the custom resource as a volume.

Could anyone please point me to an example?  Another question is that should I go further and define the whole app as a custom resource?  This approach also has the issue of creating configMap with custom resources.  Thanks.

Comment: It might be easier to help answer this if you included some example snippets of some of your configuration. Can you include relevant yaml code for what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hi, Here are the Options https://github.com/fabric8io/configmapcontroller https://github.com/atombender/k8s-config-controller